# Default all threads to a core?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, scheduler, centos6

I specified a cpuset X with core 2-11, and taskset --cpu-list 2.

It seems like if I run a process with taskset nested with cpuset X, then sched_getaffinity() only sees core #2 available.

My question is that is there a way to achieve the followings:
- default all threads in a process to 1 core, AND 
- the process is "protected" by cpuset (so that no other processes will use the set of cores specified), AND
- I can still set the cpu affinities for some threads programmatically (I know how this can be done with pthread_attr_setaffinity_np())?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sched_getaffinity` only reports the _current_ cpuset, which _is_ 2.
Did you try setting the affinity to 0xFFFFFFFF (with `sched_setaffinity`), and then getting the cpuset?

Comment: I didn't try to call sched_setaffinity() before calling sched_getaffinity(). Is there a way to default all threads to 1 core and then set the affinity of threads that I care inside a CPUset?

Comment: Run your app on a 15-year-old single-core Pentium box.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put your question in this way, you want your process to run on one of the cores and prevent any other processes from running on it? In that case you should refer the command `isolcpus`.

By using the parameter `isolcpus` during boot time you can isolate one or more CPUs from the kernel scheduler unless if a process/thread requests to use the isolated CPU using CPU affinity. (Refer- http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re46.html and also- [whole one core dedicated to single process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583146/whole-one-core-dedicated-to-single-process))