# How to implement a kernel thread that never sleeps?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, watchdog

### Problem

I need a kernel thread that is able to work for prolonged periods of time without yielding, basically fully dedicating a CPU core to it on demand:

```
int my_kthread(void *arg)
{
    while(!kthread_should_stop()) {
        do_some_work();
        if(sleeping_enabled) msleep(1000);
        else {
            // What to do here to avoid lockup warnings
            // and ensure system stability?
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Background

The thread is created like this when the module that I am working on is loaded:

```
my_task = kthread_run(&my_kthread, (void *)some_data, "My KThread")
set_cpus_allowed(my_task, *cpumask_of(10)); // Pin thread to core #10
```

and stopped like this when the module is unloaded:

```
kthread_stop(my_task);
```

Everything works just fine when `sleeping_enabled` is `true`.

Otherwise, soon after the thread is started, the kernel complains of the apparent lockup.
At first, I merely aimed to avoid the various warnings such as

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#10 stuck for 22s!
```

and

```
INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks: { 10} (detected by 15, t=30567 jiffies)
```

since they tend to flood my console with dumps for all >20 cores, and the "lockup" is desired behavior.

I tried poking the watchdog like this:

```
if(sleeping_enabled) msleep(1000);
else touch_softlockup_watchdog();
```

in combination with `(echo 1 > /sys/module/rcupdate/parameters/rcu_cpu_stall_suppress)`
and pretty much got what I want (a never-sleeping thread that successfully does what I want and no spam in the console).

However, not only does this "solution" feel like cheating, it seems I am completely breaking something by hogging that one core: when unloading the module via `rmmod`, the whole system freezes. The console starts periodically dumping soft lockups on all cores, with this call trace:

```
[<ffffffff810c96b0>] ? queue_stop_cpus_work+0xd0/0xd0
[<ffffffff810c9903>] cpu_stopper_thread+0xe3/0x1b0
[<ffffffff8108639a>] ? finish_task_switch+0x4a/0xf0
[<ffffffff8169e654>] ? __schedule+0x3c4/0x700
[<ffffffff81080e98>] ? __wake_up_common+0x58/0x90
[<ffffffff810c9820>] ? __stop_cpus+0x80/0x80
[<ffffffff81077e93>] kthread+0x93/0xa0
[<ffffffff816a9724>] kernel_thread_helper+0x4/0x10
[<ffffffff81077e00>] ? flush_kthread_worker+0xb0/0xb0
[<ffffffff816a9720>] ? gs_change+0x13/0x13
```

Meanwhile, my kernel thread continues running (as evidenced by some console messages that it prints out every now and then), so it never saw `kthread_should_stop()` return `true`.

Unloading did work correctly and stopped the thread before I switched to not sleeping at all. Now, I am unable to make iterative modifications without having to reboot.

Note that I have simplified the description here a lot. I am trying to add such a thread (to poll some hardware registers and log their changes) to a GPU driver, so there may be module-dependent reasons for the freeze on unload. However, this does not change my general question about how to best implement a thread that never sleeps.

Comment: You need to let other things run on that CPU sometimes.  Try `schedule()` in the `else` clause.  As long as no other CPU-intensive processes are trying to run on this CPU, it will return quickly.

Comment: @Peter `else schedule()` does fix the system freeze on module unload :) It takes between 5 and 20 μs to execute on my otherwise idle system. However, the registers that I am polling may change a bit faster than that (say once every 3 μs) and I would ideally like to notice every single change. Could there be an even faster way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is similar to your question ["whole one core dedicated to single process"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583146/whole-one-core-dedicated-to-single-process) , please check the replies there.

Comment: I did stumble upon that question (it is not mine), but was looking for a more flexible solution, i.e. to only temporarily hog one core instead of isolating it at boot-time. Maybe there just isn't one... But it did kind of work when I never slept. It's only when I try to unload my module that things completely break.

Comment: @Karim this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Peter I don't have enough reputation to comment!