# How to allow only a (few) specific process/thread run on a core on Linux

Tags: linux, affinity, cpu-cores

I know how to pin a process/thread to a core on Linux.

What I like to know is how to ban/exclude any other process/thread from running on that particular core.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isolcpus` to isolate the cpu core, and then migrate the processes you want on the core using `sched_setaffinity`.

If you are worried about interrupts, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13585364/1601162