# How to disable interrupts and scheduler in Linux from kernelspace?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is it possible to freeze all processors from executing code while my code is executed in kernel space?

I need to dump a large amount of data and I need the guarantee that data stays consistent during execution of my code.

local_irq_save and friends disables only for local cpu...

Comment: I guess I've find it - stop_machine() function

Comment: userland: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595735/prevent-linux-thread-from-being-interrupted-by-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were looking for something like `big kernel lock (BKL)`. But this is not available since kernel version **2.6.39**.
So you need to use finer grained locking version like `spin_lock_irqsave()` & `spin_unlock_irqrestore()` which both disables interrupts on local cpu and preemption until the lock is held.

However it is not recommended to hold spin locks for longer duration.