# FreeBSD function usage on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, sockets, ubuntu, freebsd

im trying to invoke method from FreeBSD 
`critical_enter()` and `critical_exit()` in my project.

While compiling i get an error

```
implicit declaration of function ‘critical_exit’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
implicit declaration of function ‘critical_enter’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Do you know which functions may be equivalent to these two on Ubuntu?

Comment: It does not exists, take a look here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595735/prevent-linux-thread-from-being-interrupted-by-scheduler). Why do you want to use it? it is for avoid CPU migration or it is to give the highest process priority?

Comment: Ringbuffer implementation

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong but looks like you are looking for safe thread mechanism  and you don't need critical_enter/exit what you need is mutex or semaphores.  take a look to [link]http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html#SYNCHRONIZATION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are part of the FreeBSD *kernel*.  They are not meant for user-mode programs, nor are they portable outside of the FreeBSD kernel.